# Dynamically set 'basePackages' in java annotation

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-2

I have following code to enable the JPA repository scan, but I have many packages in my project, is it able to set basePackages in a property file? as I don't want to change this class **EntityManagerConfig** in this class.

config file:

- com.mycompany.trades.jpa
- com.mycompany.system.jpa
- com.mycompany.crm.jpa

```
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.mycompany.system.jpa" }, entityManagerFactoryRef = "emf")
    @EntityScan("com.mycompany.system.jpa")
    public class EntityManagerConfig {
      //...
    }
```

Comment: You could just have it scan all of `com.mycompany`.

Comment: Recommended read: [What are the uses of `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotations?](https://springbootdev.com/2017/11/13/what-are-the-uses-of-entityscan-and-enablejparepositories-annotations/)

Comment: Thanks @Andreas what if there is another package with name started from "org.some_org.*", It is able to scan the root path with empty "" setting but it will take a long time.

Comment: You can specify more than one name, e.g. `basePackages = { "com.mycompany", "org.some_org" }`. That's why the `{ }` are there, it's an array of values, as you can also see in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#basePackages--): `String[]`